# Menubar and sidebar disappeared in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: compiz, ccsm

I have tried reinstalling compiz and compizconfig-settings-manager.

When I do `export DISPLAY=:10` and run `ccsm`. It says:

```
AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute 'get_default_screen()'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a work around to this problem after going through so many forums.
I got to run ccsm command so that i could enable the unity plugin in settings manager.
But it seems ccsm doesnt work in tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and you are unable to open terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T.
Here comes the use of Emacs GUI where you can instantiate shell and run ccsm.
And the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same questions, the reason is **compiz** which i removed ,here is my soulution:

1. make sure not **Intel Graphics driver and Nvidia Graphics drive conflict**. which you can use

   - `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

to remove the Nvidia Graphics  drive .

2. make sure you are not remove **unity-desktop**、**compiz**、**ccsm** .
   which you can reinstall that by use

   - `sudo apt-get purge unity-desktop compiz ccsm`
   - `sudo apt-get autoremove`
   - `sudo reboot`

after restart your computer `sudo apt-get install unity-desktop compiz ccsm` .

3. clear the **old error gnome configure files**

   - `cd ~`
   - `ls -all`
   - `sudo rm -rf .gnome2/ .gnome2_private/ .config/ .gconfd/ .gconf/ .gnome/`

restart your computer , hope it can help you!!